# float 7 numbers to left of decimal

Tags: php

I need to get numbers in order but need them to be like this

```
0000001
0000002
0000003
etc.
```

I have tried a few different lines of code and nothing works. It always puts the 7 placed to the right of the decimal like this 1.0000000, 2.0000000

Here is what I currently have

```
$i = 0000001;
while ($i != 0001001){
$i = number_format("$i",7);
echo $i."<br />";
$i++;
}
```

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sprintf`:

```
sprintf("%07d",$i);
```

So instead of `number_format`:

```
$i = 0000001;
while ($i != 0001001) {
    $i = sprintf("%07d", $i);
    echo $i . "<br />";
    $i++;
}
```

---

- [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) — Format a number with grouped thousands
- [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) — Return a formatted string